# Core Data Multithreading violation

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data

I am getting a Core Data multithreading violation. Even if am using `performBlockAndWait`. I am having an `NSOperation` subclass to perform BG fetch for cloud kit. Below is the code.  It crashes after all the execution finishes.

```
override public func main() {
 self.localStoreMOC?.performBlockAndWait({ () -> Void in 
            do
            {
                try self.fetchTest()
                self.syncCompletionBlock!(syncError: nil)
            }
            catch let error as NSError
            {
                let userInfo:Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [CKSIncrementalStoreError: error];

                let error1 = NSError(domain: CKSIncrementalStoreSyncOperationErrorDomain, code: CKSErrorCode.CKSErrorDatabaseError.rawValue, userInfo: userInfo)
                self.syncCompletionBlock!(syncError: error)

            }
   })
}

func fetchTest() throws
{
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K != %@", CKSIncrementalStoreLocalStoreChangeTypeAttributeName, NSNumber(short: CKSLocalStoreRecordChangeType.RecordNoChange.rawValue))

    var deletedManagedObjects:Array<AnyObject> = Array<AnyObject>()
    var insertedOrUpdatedManagedObjects:Array<AnyObject> = Array<AnyObject>()

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: self.entityNames1.objectAtIndex(self.tableIndex) as! String)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "modifiedDateL", ascending: false)]
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    fetchRequest.fetchOffset = self.fetchOffset
    fetchRequest.fetchLimit = self.batchSize

    var results: [AnyObject]?
    do
    {

        results = try self.localStoreMOC?.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)

        if results != nil && results?.count > 0
        {
            insertedOrUpdatedManagedObjects += (results!.filter({(object)->Bool in

                let managedObject:NSManagedObject = object as! NSManagedObject

                if (managedObject.valueForKey(CKSIncrementalStoreLocalStoreChangeTypeAttributeName)) as! NSNumber == NSNumber(short: CKSLocalStoreRecordChangeType.RecordUpdated.rawValue)
                {
                    return true
                }
                if (managedObject.valueForKey(CKSIncrementalStoreLocalStoreChangeTypeAttributeName)) as! NSNumber == NSNumber(short: CKSLocalStoreRecordChangeType.RecordInserted.rawValue)
                {
                    return true
                }
                return false
            }))

            deletedManagedObjects += (results!.filter({(object)->Bool in

                let managedObject:NSManagedObject = object as! NSManagedObject
                if (managedObject.valueForKey(CKSIncrementalStoreLocalStoreChangeTypeAttributeName)) as! NSNumber == NSNumber(short: CKSLocalStoreRecordChangeType.RecordDeleted.rawValue)
                {

                    return true
                }
                return false
            }))


            self.totalItems = insertedOrUpdatedManagedObjects.count + deletedManagedObjects.count
            self.fetchOffset = self.fetchOffset + self.batchSize

            print("totalItems : \(self.totalItems) fetchOffset : \(self.fetchOffset) results \(results)")
            if self.totalItems < self.defaultBatchSize
            {
                self.batchSize = self.defaultBatchSize - self.totalItems
            }

        }
        else
        {
            self.tableIndex++
            self.fetchOffset = 0
        }

    }
    catch let error1 as NSError
    {
        insertedOrUpdatedManagedObjects.removeAll()
        deletedManagedObjects.removeAll()
        results = nil
        throw error1
    }
}
```

[image: Line of Crash along with thread trace]

EDIT 1:

I Narrowed the crash down, but am still not able to figure out the reason for crash. The code works properly if i do not store the results in deletedManagedObjects, insertedOrUpdatedManagedObjects. But if i do it crashes after the completion of NSoperation.

Edit 2: 
Have Added a screenshot of line of crash and thread trace.

Comment: Make sure you've read thoroughly the following in Core Data and concurrency: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint in your debugger for "All Exceptions" and run the test again.  Where does the breakpoint fire?

From the reading of your question, it appears you are *assuming* the problem is here.

What line of code exactly is throwing the exception?

### Update 1

Based on your updated question, the issue is that you are touching instances of `NSManagedObject` outside of the queue they were created on which is a violation of the rules.  What are you doing with these objects once the `NSOperation` completes?

Comment: the All Exception break point does not fire at all. It just provides me with CoreDataViolation. Have attached the Thread Trace.

Comment: I do not use the objects outside the NSoperation. The completion block just shows a alert that the operation is successful. Have removed all the code from completion block still it shows that same violation  warning. The breakpoint use to fire on "executeFetchRequest" so i isolated the code to check what i was doing wrong.

Comment: Thing i observed was if i comment the code after the execute fetch request in the code above it works fine without any warning, If i do use the code then it shows multithreadingviolation, even if i do not return the objects from method.  The violation warning occurs after the operation completes. The device is iOS 8.3 and Xcode 7.2

Comment: Again, without knowing what line of code the break point rests on when the violation fires, you are only guessing.  Show the line that the break point fires.

Comment: Have added the screenshot with line of crash with the code as above.

Comment: Marcus S. Zara: I observed that if i use performblock instead of performblockAndWait it does not provide the violation. So it is the issue for autorelease managed objects ?

Comment: @user3519594 And what is spit out to the console?

Comment: The console does not have anything. But i resolved the issue i just have to put a autorelease pool inside the main method and all the code inside it.